# How to get stringResource if not in a composable function

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I have a `Jetpack Compose` app that uses `stringResource` everywhere and it works great for `localization`.

But, I have a few functions that are no `Composable` Functions and I would like to retrieve the string from the `resources`.  When I try to use `stringResource` in those functions it tells me it can only be used in a composable.

So, how do I get a string from a resource if I am not a composable function?

Comment: Something like `context.resources.getString(R.string.myString)`

Comment: Yes, but how do I get context in a non-composable

Comment: Just passing it as a parameter for example.

Comment: Yes, but the calling function is not a composable either so I cannot get the context.  Actually I have a class and I am calling a utility function to get me the string, but the utility function is a composable so I cannot call it from the class. I guess I could pass the context to the class, but it all seems messy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure if I understand it correctly, but is it like this?

```
@Composable
fun Composable() {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val someString = NonComposable(context)
}

fun NonComposable(context: Context): String =
    context.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)
```

Recommendation: You can also define a `sealed class` that has 2 types where you can supply your intended string parameter, an actual `String` `value` and a `String` `resource` where you can specify how they're going to be resolved.

`UiText`

```
sealed class UiText {

data class StringValue(val str: String): UiText()

class StringResource(
    @StringRes val resourceId: Int,
    vararg val args: Any
): UiText()

@Composable
fun asString(): String {
    return when (this) {
        is StringValue -> {
            str
        }
        is StringResource -> {
            stringResource(id = resourceId, formatArgs = args)
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage scope:

Inside your `ViewModel` where you can simply supply the id of the string resource

```
var stringResourceVariable = UiText.StringResource(R.string.some_string_resource)
```

Then in your `Composable`

```
viewModel.stringResourceVariable.asString()
```

you can simply invoke `asString` and it will be resolved depending on what type of `UiText` string you supplied.

The benefit of having this approach, is you won't have any problems supplying string resources in your `ViewModel`.

Comment: Yes, and that is what I am doing now.  I just did not have the context in the non-composable becuase it was called from another non-composable.  SO, I added the var and pass it all the way through.  I guess I was looking for a way to not have to pas the context everywhere.  Thanks for the reply in any case.